# @Google-cloud/task module not found (pnpm)

Tags: pnpm, google-cloud-tasks, pnpm-workspace

I recently migrated an app to a monorepo using turborepo and pnpm. During the build process, I encountered an error that didn't occur when the next app used yarn. Notably, when building the old app on Vercel, this issue didn't arise.

I suspect the error is related to how pnpm performs lookups. I'm curious about why Vercel doesn't fail the build in this case. Could it be because the package is used in a route handler instead of a page route? In the Vercel build logs, the error is marked as such, but locally it's not marked as an error.

Any insights on how to address this issue would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: usually the easiest solution is to set `node-linker=hoisted` in `.npmrc`, remove node_modules and run `pnpm install`

Comment: @ZoltanKochan I read about this config option after your suggestion and It felt like it would solve the issue. But it actually remains hmm.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to use yarn with this .yarnc.yml config:
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.4.1.cjs

Same issue.. so I guess the issue is perhaps related to using @google-cloud/tasks in a monorepo/turborepo?

Comment: Also tried to use yarn 1.19.0, same issue.